# Sed substitution and external command

Tags: bash, sed

I have an input log file in this format

```
May 23 2012 11:59:56
a;b;c
May 21 2012 16:54:12
d;e;f
May 19 2012 16:22:52
g;h;i
...
```

I would want to output it in this format

```
2012-05-23
a;b;c
2012-05-21
d;e;f
2012-05-19
g;h;i
...
```

Using `sed`, I know how to substitute the date lines

```
% sed 's/.*:.*:.*/match_string/' input.txt
match_string
a;b;c
match_string
d;e;f
match_string
g;h;i
...
```

Using `date`, I know how to convert dates :

```
% date -d 'May 23 2012 11:59:56' '+%Y-%m-%d'
2012-05-23
```

But how can make match_string to be evaluated during the sed command ?

Comment: You probably meant to say `May 23 ...` instead of `May May 23 ...` in your `date` command.

Comment: I corrected the typing mistakes, sorry for that.

Comment: Is an external command necessary? see http://sed.sf.net/grabbag/tutorials/lookup_tables.txt

Comment: Date conversion isn't an easy task, I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have **GNU Sed** available, you could use the `e` flag:

```
sed 's/.*:.*/date -d"&" "+%Y-%m-%d"/ge' file
```

will help you for your example, see the test:

```
kent$  echo "May 23 2012 11:59:56
a;b;c
May 21 2012 16:54:12
d;e;f
May 19 2012 16:22:52
g;h;i"|sed 's/.*:.*/date -d"&" "+%Y-%m-%d"/ge'
2012-05-23
a;b;c
2012-05-21
d;e;f
2012-05-19
g;h;i
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Perl for this:

```
perl -pe '$_ = qx{ date -d "$_" +%F } if $. % 2 == 1'
```

Of course Perl can do what date does:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lpe '
    $_ = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%b %d %Y %T")->ymd if $. % 2 == 1
'
```

Comment: The question was about sed. I know we can do similar things in awk, python... It just depends what you already know.

Comment: Don't forget that the answers aren't just for you.

Comment: I know this, but I searched for similar questions before that. And all the answers were about the different possibilities in awk, perl etc. It's like asking for a question in C++ and getting an answer in Java. Very confusing.