# Can envsubst not do in-place substitution?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a config file which contains some ENV_VARIABLE styled variables.

```
This is my file.
It might contain $EXAMPLES of text.
```

Now I want that variable replaced with a value which is saved in my actual environment variables. So I'm trying this:

```
export EXAMPLES=lots
envsubst < file.txt > file.txt
```

But it doesn't work when the input file and output file are identical. The result is an empty file of size 0.

There must be a good reason for this, some bash basics that I'm not aware of?
How do I achieve what I want to do, ideally without first outputting to a different file and then replacing the original file with it?

I know that I can do it easily enough with `sed`, but when I discovered the `envsubst` command I thought that it should be perfect for my use case, so I'd like to use that.

Comment: You never accepted the best answer. I think this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/74551579/465183

Answer (score 30):

Here is the solution that I use:

```
originalfile="file.txt"
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
cp --attributes-only --preserve $originalfile $tmpfile
cat $originalfile | envsubst > $tmpfile && mv $tmpfile $originalfile
```

Be careful with other solutions that do not use a temporary file. Pipes are asynchronous, so the file will occasionally be read after it has already been truncated.

Comment: This may change the permissions of `file.txt`, since the temporary file may not have the same permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @maiermic. I have updated the code to preserve file permissions.

Comment: What's the point of `tee` here? That dumps the output into stdout, presumably the console, which seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @rici, I think you are right. I edited the answer by replacing `tee` with `>`. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Upvoted for using good names and --long-form options. Readability is incredibly important.

Answer (score 23):

To avoid creating a temporary file, use `sponge` not `tee`:

```
envsubst < file.txt | sponge file.txt
```

From https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge:

> sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file. Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening the output file. This allows constricting pipelines that read from and write to the same file.

Comment: This is the most elegant way

Comment: Beautiful, I've never heard of this before. Is this specific to any shell or distro or would this also work in GNU and on Mac?

Comment: @peedee [sponge binary](https://command-not-found.com/sponge) is a part of `moreutils` package

Answer (score 16):

Redirects are handled by the shell, not the program being executed, and they are set up before the program is invoked.

The redirect `>output.file` has the effect of creating `output.file` if it doesn't exist and emptying it if it does. Either way, you end up with an empty file, and that is what the program's output is redirected to.

Programs like `sed` which are capable of "in-place" modification must take the filename as a command-line argument, not as a redirect.

In your case, I would suggest using a temporary file and then renaming it if all goes OK.

Answer (score 12):

I found another shortcut to put into temp file and then rename it to original file.

```
envsubst < in.txt > out.txt && mv out.txt in.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

```
envsubst < file.txt | tee file.txt
```

Caution: @SoftwareFactor rightly pointed out in the comments that this answer suffers from a race condition and can cause the resulting file to be empty at random.

Comment: This actually works! You can glue it with find if you want to do recursive substitution. `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'envsubst < $1 | tee' -- {} \;`

Comment: Be careful with this answer. It has a race condition. Pipes are asynchronous, so ```envsubst``` will occasionally read the file after ```tee``` has already truncated it.

Try running the following experiment - you will see that your file will become empty:
```for i in {0..1000}; do envsubst < file.txt | tee file.txt; done```

Comment: @kboom I think it is really has some race condition. isn't it better to do `find . -type f -exec /bin/sh -c 'envsubst < $1 > $1.tmp && mv $1.tmp $1' -- {} \;`

Comment: BE CAREFUL !!! 
Thanks to @SoftwareFactor. Sometimes in our CI we faced an undefined behavior. It required long time to realize the issue was in race condition from the command as in answer !

Comment: See the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74551579/465183

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve in-place substitution by calling envsubst from gnu sed with the ["e" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957889/sed-substitution-and-external-command):

```
EXAMPLES=lots sed -i 's/.*/echo & | envsubst/e' file.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work on mac: `sed -i 's/.*/echo & | envsubst/e' infra/codedeploy/scripts/install_dependencies
sed: 1: "infra/codedeploy/script ...": command i expects \ followed by text`

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno it works if you install _gnu_ sed, which is not the default on macos.

But I wouldn't recommend this solution anyways, because `&` is unquoted and will lead to errors (best case) or unwanted command executions (worst case).

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the `mv` solution won't maintain file permissions. Using `cp -pf` would be preferable in the case that you're modifying an executable file.

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
cat file.txt | envsubst > "$tmpfile" && cp -pf "$tmpfile" file.txt
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Comment: This may change the permissions of `file.txt`, since the temporary file may not have the same permissions.

Comment: That’s what `-p` does by preserving permissions, no?

Comment: `-p` preserves the permissions of the source file, which is the temporary file and not the original file (`file.txt`). See https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html

Answer (score 1):

Updated 20221011 - Using 1 sed command

```
sed -i -r 's/["`]|\$\(/\\&/g; s/.*/echo "&"/ e' ./input.txt
```

Updated 20221007 - Using 2 sed commands

```
sed -i -r 's/["`]|\$\(/\\&/g' input.txt
sed -i -r 's/.*/echo "&"/ e' input.txt
```

Do it without envsubst

```
envsubst_file () {
    local original_file=$1
    local temp_file=$(mktemp)
    trap "rm -f ${temp_file}" 0 2 3 15
    cp -p ${original_file} ${temp_file}
    cat ${original_file} | sed -r 's/["`]|\$\(/\\&/g' | sed -r 's/.*/echo "&"/g' | sh > ${temp_file}
    mv ${temp_file} ${original_file}
}

envsubst_file 'input.txt'
```

First using sed to escapes double quotes("), backtick(`) and command $( by prefixing with backslash(\),then using sed again replace with

```
echo "&"
```

Finally executing the shell script and redirecting to ${temp_file}

Answer (score 0):

This answer was framed from two other answers. I guess this is the best solution.

```
originalFile=file.txt
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
cat $originalFile | envsubst > "$tmpfile" && cp -pf "$tmpfile" $originalFile
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash, check this:

```
a=`<file.txt` && envsubst <<<"$a" >file.txt
```

Tested on 500mb file, works as expected.

Answer (score -3):

In the end I found that using `envsubst` was too dangerous after all. My files might contain dollar signs in places where I don't want any substitution to happen, and `envsubst` will just replace them with empty strings if no corresponding environment variable is defined. Not cool.

Comment: In that case you need to explicitly specify which env vars to interpolate. It will not touch those that are not listed. ie. `envsubst "$MYVARS" < source > destination`

Comment: Thanks for this tip, @lisak! I had to use single quotes, e.g. `envsubst '${PARAMETER}' < source > destination`...