# Deploy and customize a VueJs app using Docker and GitlabCI

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

i made a VueJS app, basically a website administration app that allows to display / edit data using different APIs.
This app is customizable using env variables (VUE_APP_XXX) : the urls of the APIs, the title, the color theme etc... About 30 variables, but i will certainly add other ones in the future.

For now i deploy my app using Gitlab CI, i have this Dockerfile (i remove most of env variables for clarification) :

```
# build
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ARG VUE_APP_API_URL
ARG VUE_APP_DATA_URL
ENV VUE_APP_API_URL $VUE_APP_API_URL
ENV VUE_APP_DATA_URL $VUE_APP_DATA_URL
RUN npm run build

# production
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and the gitlab-ci.yml :

```
docker-build:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - |
      docker build --pull 
      --build-arg VUE_APP_API_URL="$CI_TEST_API_URL" 
      --build-arg VUE_APP_DATA_URL="$CI_TEST_DATA_URL" 
      -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  only:
    - dev
  when: manual
```

Then on my server i just make a `docker run...` to launch my app. Everything works fine, except that :

- i have to specify all the variables manually in the Dockerfile and gitlab-ci.yml
- the resulting docker image could contain "sensible" data such as logins and passwords
- i have to create one image per instance of my app

For legal reasons i need to create one repository per app, and one repository per website (beacause each of these could have a different owner).

So my question is : what would be the best approach to deploy many instances of this app, for many websites ? Knowing that each website needs its own admin app, that can be hosted on its own server.

I'm quite a newbie to docker, i was thinking of :

- creating a docker image for a generic app, with default env variables (maybe just with the code, without the npm run build step ?)
- using this docker image to create a container for each instance, using its own env variables (is it possible to build the app with docker compose ?)

I'm quite confused about where/when to build the VueJs app, and what tools to use for that.
Any help appreciated, thanks !

**Update :**
following taleodor suggestion, i found this [medium post](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-js-runtime-environment-variables-807fa8f68665) that seems to do the job. I found it a little 'tricky' but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a docker image and then deploy it, every tool has a way to override Environment variables baked into the image itself.

So, for your example, with plain docker you could do

```
docker run -e VUE_APP_API_URL=http://my.url ...
```

And this would essentially override VUE_APP_API_URL variable previously set on the container. Again, any orchestration platform (docker compose, swarm, kubernetes etc) has capability to override environment variables as this is a very common scenario.

So usual approach I use - pre-fill environment variables inside the image with most generic values and then override them on actual deployments - then you don't need many images (many images for the same thing would be an anti-pattern).

If you have more questions - feel free to join our community discord and you can ask me there - https://discord.gg/UTxjBf9juQ

**Update (following comment below):** For the static images with compiled UI code, the algorithm is to run some entrypoint script that would do substitution over compiled files. Sample workable pattern is following (you might need tweaks to get it done right, but this gives the idea):

Assuming you're using nginx as a base image, create entrypoint.sh file that would look something like (see this SO for some references: [Can envsubst not do in-place substitution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35078753/can-envsubst-not-do-in-place-substitution)):

```
#!/bin/sh
find /usr/share/nginx/html/*.js -type f -exec sh -c "cat {} | envsubst | tee {}.tmp && mv {}.tmp {}" \;
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

2. Copy this entrypoint.sh file into your docker image and use it with ENTRYPOINT instruction.

Comment: Hmm, overriding the variables in the docker run doesn't work for me... i guess it's because the docker image contains the compiled version of the vuejs app, so the vuejs app is not compiled again at runtime ? therefor specifying new values for the variables has no effect (how would it replace the values in the 'compiled' js ?)

Comment: Good point, updated the answer - will require you some work to get this right, but gives the idea.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i found a way as edited in my original post !